# Is it possible to connect this printer to this specific router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printing, printer

I have a problem with connecting my printer to network.

Router is **Technicolor TC7200** (low-end default UPC ISP device) and printer is **HP LaserJet P2015DN**.

Here's simple image how connections in my network look like:

[image]

I have no idea how to connect this printer to router. I've tried everything and this is some informations I got:

- Ethernet LEDs on the back of printer are blinking properly, I suppose (yellow is constant, green is blinking)
- router's control panel is very poor but in tab "DHCP Clients" I can only find PC1 and PC2 (according to network configuration testpage, DHCP is "Enabled" in this printer)
- network configuration testpage also says that printer's status is "Ready", it has correct 100Mbps "Link speed", there are enabled BOOTP, AUTOIP, LPD printing, Bonjour, HP SLP, SNMP.
- Printer's host name is dhcppc19, IP address is 10.0.0.3, default gateway is 10.0.0.1
- I can ping or tracert 10.0.0.3 from PC1, pings are <1ms
- Both PCs are on Windows 7 (of course I've tried "Add printer" option, it couldn't find dhcppc19 nor 10.0.0.3 while putting these names on host/IP address and after that adding the port was a mess)
- Printer is working :) it has been connected to PC2 via USB and it worked

I don't know what else I could add. IPs of PCs in this network start from 192.168.0.1x.

I'm not even sure if it's possible to connect printer to this router - this is very low model (even USB port is blocked on it), got it from the ISP and for now I have to use it.

Any help how to make it visible on any PC via Ethernet?

Comment: 10.0.x.x and 192.168 are not in the same network, I'm surprised you could ping actually. It sounds like the printer is configured with a static (not dhcp assigned) IP.  Either get the printer to ask dhcp for an ip or change it to a static 192.168.0.xx IP.  Gateway would be the routers ip likely 192.168.0.1

Comment: Yea router's gateway IP is 192.168.0.1. But how to change printer's IP to static 192.168.0.xx?

Comment: @adek111 Read the user manual!. p53 network settings. https://www.uvm.edu/cosmolab/om/HP2015manual.pdf

Comment: @DavidPostill sorry but HP ToolboxFX is not working on Windows 7

Comment: @adek111 As that seems to be the only way to configure the IP address you should resolve that problem first.

Comment: @DavidPostill I would love to know how :) google is deaf, HP site says about workarounds to this program only "how to check cartridges", nothing about workarounds to IP configuration. Also, I don't have any other system - the oldest one here is Win7 mentioned before.

Comment: <shrug> attach the printer to a PC and share the printer. Or buy a new printer. Yours is from 2007 so nearly 10 years old ...

Comment: this is not the way I'd like to connect printer because it requires PC to be launched. so this is not a solution. EDIT: before I had a printer from '90 and I was still able to use it, buying the newest stuff is not always a solution and I'm living in 3rd world country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution after long few hours of trying. The solution is very simple and seemingly very stupid but it works (so it's not stupid).

@Tyson answer was a good tip, I also found similar answer in Google so I supposed this is a right track.

If I couldn't change IP of printer to 192.168.0.x, I made an **inverse**. I changed IP of router from 192.168.0.1 to 10.0.0.0 and it works... :) "DHCP Clients" finds it; also remember to start PCs' IPs a bit higher if you have similar option (my start PC-IP is now 10.0.0.10).

That's it, as simple as that. No need to *"buy new printer"* or anything. Works like a charm.

//---------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT: Important stuff!**

Printer works like a charm, but changing IP of network resulted with random internet problems on some devices (of course I reconfigured all of them, but randomly some devices were working, some of them not, and some were working sometimes and very slow).

***How to fix?***

1) Change router IP to 10.0.x.x like I wrote before.

2) Finally I could gain access to printer settings (write 10.0.0.3 in browser), then configure printer to 192.168.x.x or anything you want.

3) Reconfigure router IP to 192.168.x.x

Printer works, all devices work now.